# Retorno Null mesmo com registro no banco SQLIte

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estou com um problemas para fazer essa consulta onde estou procurando por pelo codigo de produto e codigo do atendimento. Se faço um select sem WHERE obtenho resultados mas fazendo essa forma meu objeto ProdutoAtendimento sempre retorna null o que posso estar errando nesta consulta.

```
   @Override
    public ProdutoAtendimento  pesquisarPorProdutoEAtendimento(DatabaseHelper db,int codigoProduto,int codigoAtendimento) {
        ProdutoAtendimento produto = new ProdutoAtendimento();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + IDatabaseHelper.TABLE_PRODUTO_ATENDIMENTO +
                " WHERE " + IDatabaseHelper.COL_ID_PRODUTO_ATENDIMENTO + " = "+codigoProduto+
                " AND "  + IDatabaseHelper.COL_ID_ATENDIMENTO + " = "+codigoAtendimento;
                ;
    //    String whereArgs[] = new String[]{String.valueOf(codigo)};

        //Definir MODO de LEITURA nas TABELAS
        this.db = db.getReadableDatabase();

        //Criar CURSOR para os resultados
        Cursor c = this.db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        // Se retornou resultados
        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            //Adicionar resultados na lista
            do{
                produto.setIdAtendimento(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(IDatabaseHelper.COL_ID_ATENDIMENTO)));
                produto.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(IDatabaseHelper.COL_ID_PRODUTO_ATENDIMENTO)));
                produto.setDescricao(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(IDatabaseHelper.COL_DESCRICAO_PRODUTO_ATENDIMENTO)));
                produto.setSerial(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(IDatabaseHelper.COL_SERIAL_PRODUTO_ATENDIMENTO)));
                produto.setQuantidade(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(IDatabaseHelper.COL_QUANTIDADE_PRODUTO_ATENDIMENTO)));
                produto.setUnidade(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(IDatabaseHelper.COL_UNIDADE_PRODUTO_ATENDIMENTO)));
                produto.setControleUnidade(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(IDatabaseHelper.COL_CONTOLA_UNIDADE_PRODUTO_ATENDIMENTO)));
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }

        //Fechar o cursor
        if (!c.isClosed()){
            c.close();
        }

        this.db.close();
        return produto;
    }
```

Comment: Tentou fazer com o db.query() pra ver se chega a retornar algum dado?

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática não tentei. mas vou fazer um teste agora.

Comment: Blz. Só lembra de trocar a query para passar os parametros do where com "?" e também de passar os parametros na mesma ordem do where. QUalquer coisa a doc do SQLiteDatabase pode dar um help.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática, poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nesse link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40210690/7762411) do SOen, la tem descrito certinho como fazer.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática fiz um teste aqui, com meu código mesmo se eu passo somente um paramentro no SQL ele me retorna. agora com os dois não.

Comment: Consegui resolver, obrigado pela dica.